# Carrito de compras con JS

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

estoy intentando hacer un carrito de compras basico sin  PHP ni base de datos , tengo un array "carta" que contiene cada producto de la clase "Productos". En el html son 12 cards con un boton de agregar al carrito en cada una con el mismo id para todos, necesito que cada vez que haga click en el boton de agregar , eso se pushee al array "carrito" y despues se imprima en el bodyCarrito (el carrito de compras es un off canva de bootstrap 5). El problema es el siguiente , cuando voy al local storage me agrega todos los productos como un solo array de un lenght de 12 objetos, cuando solo necesito que se agregue el del boton correspondiente, pero a través del console.log (localStorage.setItem("Productos", JSON.stringify(carrito))) aparece como "undefined".

```
   class Productos {
    constructor(id, tipo, nombre, precio) {
        this.id = id;
        this.tipo = tipo;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.precio = precio;
    }
}
//Pizzas
const pizza1 = new Productos(1,"Pizza","Salsiccia",950);
const pizza2 = new Productos(2,"Pizza","Margherita",1000);
const pizza3 = new Productos(3,"Pizza","Rucula",1200);
const pizza4 = new Productos(4,"Pizza","Aglio e Cepolla",1200);
//Pastas
const pasta1 = new Productos(5,"Pasta","Spaghetti alla Carbonara",520);
const pasta2 = new Productos(6,"Pasta","Penne Rigatti Mediterráneo",750);
const pasta3 = new Productos(7,"Pasta","Frutti di Mare",980);
const pasta4 = new Productos(8,"Pasta","Pappardelle alla Bolognese",650);
//Vinos
const vino1 = new Productos(9,"Vino","Chateaneuf du Pape",1500);
const vino2 = new Productos(10,"Vino","Madame Cliquot",2000);
const vino3 = new Productos(11,"Vino","Campo Viejo Rioja DOM",950);
const vino4 = new Productos(12,"Vino","Burra Brook vino blanco",1100);

//Arrays a utilizar
let Carta = [pizza1,pizza2,pizza3,pizza4,
    pasta1,pasta2,pasta3,pasta4,vino1,vino2,vino3,vino4]

let carrito = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Productos")) ?? []

let bodyCarrito = document.querySelector("#canvaCarritoBody")
let btnLimpiar = document.querySelector("#btnLimpiar")
let btnCarrito = document.querySelector("#btnCarrito")

btnCarrito.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    switch (Carta) {
        case pizza1:
            carrito.push(`${nombre} $${precio}`)
        break;
        case pizza2:
            carrito.push(`${nombre} $${precio}`)
        break;
        case pizza2:
            carrito.push(`${nombre} $${precio}`)
        break;
        case pizza3:
            carrito.push(`${nombre} $${precio}`)
        break;
        case pizza4:
            carrito.push(`${nombre} $${precio}`)
        break;
        case pasta1:
            carrito.push(`${nombre} $${precio}`)
        break;
        case pasta2:
            carrito.push(`${nombre} $${precio}`)
        break;
        case pasta3:
            carrito.push(`${nombre} $${precio}`)
        break;
        case pasta4:
            carrito.push(`${nombre} $${precio}`)
        break;
        case vino1:
            carrito.push(`${nombre} $${precio}`)
        break;
        case vino2:
            carrito.push(`${nombre} $${precio}`)
        break;
        case vino3:
            carrito.push(`${nombre} $${precio}`)
        break;
        case vino4:
            carrito.push(`${nombre} $${precio}`)
        break;
    }
    
    if(Carta.some(producto  => producto.nombre === `${this.nombre}` )){
        let index = Carta.findIndex(producto => producto.nombre === `${this.nombre}` )
        Carta[index].cant++
    }else{
        let productoCarrito = {
            ...Carta,
            cant: 1
        }
        carrito.push(productoCarrito)
    }
  
})
console.log (localStorage.setItem("Productos", JSON.stringify(carrito))) 
carrito.forEach((element) => {
    bodyCarrito.innerHTML += `<div class=" mx-auto bg-info">
    <h3>${element.nombre}</h3>
    <h4> Precio unitario: ${element.precio} </h4>
    <h4> Cantidad:  ${element.cantidad} </h4>
    </div>`
});

btnLimpiar.addEventListener("click", () =>{
    bodyCarrito.innerHTML += ""
})

const calcularTotal = () =>{

    let total = carrito.reduce((acc, ite)=>acc + ite.precio * ite.cantidad ,0)

   bodyCarrito.innerHTML = `<h6 class="bg-danger">El total es : $${total}</h6>`
    ;
}
```

Comment: si bien ni me equivoco este codigo `btnCarrito.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    switch (Carta) {`agrega todo al carro, donde discriminas que solo sea un producto, por que no esta toso el codigo, hay cosas que me hacen falta.

Comment: Por cierto `console.log(localStorage.setItem())` siempre va a dar `undefined`. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem)